# Python ImportError on Ubuntu: No module named app.urls

Tags: django, apache, python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04, importerror

I recently installed Ubuntu with Apache, Python and Django for a school project. I am having issues with actually getting it up and running though. I followed this [tutorial](http://www.lennu.net/2012/05/14/django-deployement-installation-to-ubuntu-12-dot-04-server/)

Everything worked as shown. I got the default "It worked!" page. My issue came when I started actually adding my apps for the project. I am getting the following error:

```
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] Internal Server Error: /login
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 92, in get_response
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error]     response = middleware_method(request)
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 69, in process_request
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error]     if (not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 551, in is_valid_path
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error]     resolve(path, urlconf)
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 440, in resolve
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error]     return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 319, in resolve
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error]     for pattern in self.url_patterns:
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 347, in url_patterns
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error]     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 342, in urlconf_module
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error]     self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error]     __import__(name)
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error]   File "/srv/pumpit/pumpit2/pumpitproj/pumpitproj/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error]     url(r'^login/', include('pumpitproj.loginhandler.urls')),
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 25, in include
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error]     urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error]     __import__(name)
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] ImportError: No module named loginhandler.urls
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] mod_wsgi (pid=18637): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/srv/pumpit/pumpit2/conf/apache/django.wsgi'.
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 178, in get_response
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 217, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 69, in technical_500_response
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 298, in get_traceback_html
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     return t.render(c)
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 140, in render
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     return self._render(context)
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     return self.nodelist.render(context)
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 830, in render
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     bit = self.render_node(node, context)
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     return node.render(context)
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 84, in render
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 606, in resolve
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaultfilters.py", line 715, in date
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     return format(value, arg)
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 312, in format
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     return df.format(format_string)
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 35, in format
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     pieces.append(force_text(getattr(self, piece)()))
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 216, in r
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     return self.format('D, j M Y H:i:s O')
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 35, in format
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     pieces.append(force_text(getattr(self, piece)()))
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 99, in force_text
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     s = s.__unicode__()
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 130, in __text_cast
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     return func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 71, in ugettext
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     return _trans.ugettext(message)
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 276, in ugettext
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     return do_translate(message, 'ugettext')
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 258, in do_translate
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     _default = translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 172, in translation
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 154, in _fetch
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     app = import_module(appname)
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]   File "/srv/pumpit/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     __import__(name)
[Tue Apr 02 18:20:27 2013] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] ImportError: No module named loginhandler
```

My directories are setup as follows:

```
+ srv
---+ pumpit
------+ pumpit2
---------+ conf
------------+ apache
---------+ pumpitproj
------------+ loginhandler
------------+ main
------------+ memberplanhandler
------------+ pumpitproj
------------+ site_media
```

My INSTALLED_APPS and ROOT_URLCONF in /srv/pumpit/pumpit2/pumpitproj/pumpitproj/settings.py look like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'pumpitproj.loginhandler',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'pumpitproj.urls'
```

My /srv/pumpit/pumpit2/pumpitproj/pumpitproj/urls.py is as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^login/', include('pumpitproj.loginhandler.urls')),
)
```

My /srv/pumpit/pumpit2/pumpitproj/loginhandler/urls.py is as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from loginhandler import views

urlpatterns = patterns('pumpitproj.loginhandler.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index'),
)
```

My /srv/pumpit/pumpit2/conf/apache/django.wsgi is as follows:

```
import os
import sys

root_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..',$
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root_path, 'venv/lib/python2.7/$
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root_path, 'pumpit2')))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root_path, 'pumpit2', 'pumpitpr$

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'pumpitproj.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I am not sure what else might be needed for help with this. I am sure this is something simple that I have completely overlooked.

I have spent so much time searching for answers. I seem to find lots of other people having the ImportError issue, but none of the answers I have come across that have worked for others work for me. Any help I can get would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I ended up just deleting the loginhandler folder and remaking the app and that fixed the problem. I don't know what went wrong.

Although, I apparently do not know the proper way to remove a module/app because when I tried to make the new one, it stated that a module with that name already existed. I ended up having to name it something else.

Answer (score 0):

Add your app name in installed apps properly,here you are added 'pumpitproj.loginhandler', please change this to 'loginhandler' and set your ROOT_URLCONF properly.

If you are created urls.py outside the app then set

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'
```

If you are created urls.py inside a module loginhandler then set

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'loginhandler.urls'
```

also change

```
 url(r'^login/', include('pumpitproj.loginhandler.urls'))
```

to

```
 url(r'^login/', include('loginhandler.urls'))
```

My /srv/pumpit/pumpit2/pumpitproj/loginhandler/urls.py is as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from loginhandler import views

urlpatterns = patterns('loginhandler.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index'),
)
```

Try this changes.

Comment: I have a urls.py for the project under /srv/pumpit/pumpit2/pumpitproj/pumpitproj/, which is where it seems like the error is originating from, because that one references the one under loginhandler. I changed ROOT_URLCONF to just be 'urls' and I made the other changes you suggested. I am still getting the same error, except now it just states "No module named urls" instead of "No module named loginhandler.urls".

Comment: Yes, that's what I originally had it as. I am not sure what happened, but by deleting my app folders and remaking them, I am no longer having that issue. Thanks for all of your help.